# MomentJS - how to select all days of the week by name?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How to sellect all same weekdays by using momentJS? Ex: All Mondays of current month. If the day is 15th day of the month, there are two Mondays in that month, from 0 to 15th day of the month. Maybe it is some kind of looping, because momenthJS should return two dates-one for first Monday and second for second Monday in the given range and so on.

Or is there any other way to do this by using any other JavaScript library?

Comment: Are you asking how you can get all Mondays of a given month?

Comment: Yes, that's what I need

Answer (score 0):

As you said a loop can solve this problem

- move 4 weeks before from the date you have e.g. if we were on the last monday of the month we move to the first monday of the month or a previous date (if we move to the previous month we can still get the correct dates by doing more iterations)
- get the `month` of the date you have (all the dates you get should have the same month)
- move forward from the initial date computed above a week each time and check if the new date has the same month as the input date

```js
function weekdaysFromMonth (date) {
  // all the weekdays previous/next to date should be
  // 7 days apart and also have the same month
  var month = date.get('month')
  // make sure that the start date is 4 weeks before now
  // we might go to the previous month but anyway we'll
  // get the correct dates by doing more iterations
  var start = moment(date).subtract(4 * 7, 'days')
  var dates = []

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    start.add(7, 'days')
    if (start.get('month') === month) {
      dates.push(moment(start))
    }
  }

  return dates
}

document.write(
  JSON.stringify(
    weekdaysFromMonth(moment()), null, ' '
  )
)
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: No subtracting 28 days from current day is not good idea because month usually consists of 30 days. And I need weeks from beginning of a given month to the given day

Comment: We're talking about weeks right? It doesn't matter if the month has 28/29/30/31 days, the subtraction gets a lower bound only (a date that it's ensured to be less than or equal to the first week of the given month)